# condense multiple records into single record in sas

Tags: sas

I have row data by account level and I wish to group them by the account owner as a new data. Yes will take the priority.

```
Account_Owner    Account_No    Ever_Purchase    Ever_Purchase_within_2days   Ever_Deliver_in_2weeks
Tom              12345         Yes              Yes                          No
Tom              34567         Yes              No                           Yes
Tom              09876         No               No                           No

Desired Outcome
Account_Owner    Ever_Purchase    Ever_Purchase_within_2days   Ever_Deliver_in_2weeks
Tom               Yes              Yes                          Yes
```

I am sorry that I don't have any code because I don't know where to start.

Comment: Within group `Account_owner` you want the boolean flag variables to be an `OR` down the column ? I.e., the only way to get a desired 'No' in a column is if all the rows for that column in the group are 'No' ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a DOW loop to track the group result for each `ever_*` variable in a temporary array.

```
proc format;
  value yesno .,0 = 'No' other='Yes';

data have; input 
Account_Owner  $  Account_No    Ever_Purchase $   Ever_Purchase_within_2days $  Ever_Deliver_in_2weeks $;
datalines;
Tom              12345         Yes              Yes                          No
Tom              34567         Yes              No                           Yes
Tom              09876         No               No                           No
;

data want;
  array evals(100) _temporary_; * presume never more than 100 flag variables;
  call missing (of evals(*));

  * dow loop;
  do until (last.account_owner);
    set have;
    by account_owner;

    array flags ever:;
    do _n_ = 1 to dim(flags);
      evals(_n_) = evals(_n_) or flags(_n_) = 'Yes';  * compute aggregate result;
    end;
  end;

  * move results back into original variables;
  do _n_ = 1 to dim(flags);
    flags(_n_) = put(evals(_n_), yesno.);
  end;

  * implicit output, one row per group combination;
run;
```

Note: In an alternative solution you can convert Yes/No to numeric 1/0 you can use Proc SUMMARY or Proc MEANS to computed the group result (max of var would be 1 if any Yes and 0 if all No)